# problems parsing json response from Neo4j REST API query

Tags: json, neo4j

After inserting a node containing 2 properties into a Neo4j database, how do I extract the properties ("name" and "phone") from a REST API query response? My script for querying the database is:

```
<script>
function query_database()
{
var restServerURL = "http://localhost:7474/db/data"; //local copy on windows machine
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url: restServerURL + "/cypher",
  accepts: "application/json",
  dataType:"json",
  data:{
         "query" : "start n  = node(*) return n",
         "params" : {}
  },
  success: function(data, xhr, textStatus){
                  //alert("query success!");
          //process query results here

         alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
  },
  error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                   alert(errorThrown);
  }
});
}//end of query database
```

The `"alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));"` displays the following:

```
{
"columns": [
    "n"
],
"data": [
    [
        {
            "paged_traverse": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3761/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
            "outgoing_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3761/relationships/out",
            "data": {
                "phone": "123.456.7890",
                "name": "jeff "
            },
            "traverse": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3761/traverse/{returnType}",
            "all_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3761/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
            "all_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3761/relationships/all",
            "property": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3761/properties/{key}",
            "self": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3761",
            "properties": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3761/properties",
            "outgoing_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3761/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
            "incoming_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3761/relationships/in",
            "incoming_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3761/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}",
            "extensions": {},
            "create_relationship": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3761/relationships"
        }
    ]
]
```

}

Much thanks,

Jeff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you'd get the name and phone from the response data object like this:

```
var name = data.data[0][0].data.name;
var phone = data.data[0][0].data.phone;
alert("Name is " + name + "\nPhone is " + phone);
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/be5yA/).

Comment: Brian - Thanks for the quick and excellent response. Works great!

Comment: @JeffA please consider upvoting/accepting answer if it solves your problem (suggesting because you seem to be new here).

Comment: @Gopi - Thanks, I was wondering how to do that and your post prompted me to find out. Done.